# Select value if two cell are equals (Two distinct tables)

Tags: r, extract

so i'm triying to get a value from a reference table under condition based on some ID column

```
ID = c("A","B","C","D","E")
code = c(1,2,3,4,5) 
Ref= data.frame(ID,code)


ID = c("A","B","B","C","D","Z")
df= data.frame(ID)
```

matching value would be `c("1","2","2","3","4","Na")`

And i want to get the matching value Like  " check if df$ID == Ref$ID if yes get Ref$code on the matching line "  in aplication " B is in Ref ID -> 2 is the code " or "" Z is not in Ref ID -> Na is the code "

Last thing i tried is something like

```
ifelse(unlist(df$ID ) %in% Ref$ID , 
       Ref[,(which(unlist(df$ID ) %in% Ref$ID))],  'NA')
```

The test works well but i cant exctract the proper value (here y was trying to get the line with which)

**I am not trying to create a new column but just to get the value and inject it in a formula**

**Edit** : Is there a way to not merge but just to get the value ?
I have my colected data and i need to aply a formula. To do so
i need to get the corect Coef (named code here) from a Ref table. I know i can merge, im asking if it its possible to not merge but create a fonction that go Row by row search for that Coef (like the merge do), apply it and give the result in a new column.

"For each n Row check  df$ID and Ref$ID take coresponding Ref$code and do  like Zn = code * (some other parameters in df); print each Z in a new column in df on the coresponding row"

But i can merge if ther is no other solution or if it is the best solution.

Thanks all for your help

Comment: This is a merge/join operation using the 'ID' variable as the key/by variable. Specifically a 'left join'. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right for all the options. E.g. in base R it's `merge(df, Ref, by="ID", all.x=TRUE)`

Comment: I think your `Ref` should be `data.frame(ID,code)`, is that right?

Comment: Hi, thanks i corected the question and made an Edit section.
  As i said in the edit, i want to know if i can do some kind of function instead of merging the table. Thx again
And yes if ther is no beter way ill happily give upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `merge`

```
> merge(df, Ref, all.x = TRUE)
  ID code
1  A    1
2  B    2
3  B    2
4  C    3
5  D    4
6  Z   NA
```